# MVC validation message not displaying

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I cant get the MVC validation messages to show in my form, the controller validates the model state as false but the validation message is not displayed.

My Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Admin User")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Admin User Account Details are Required")]
    public string AdminUser { get; set; }
    public string AdminPassword { get; set; }
}
```

My View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AdminPage", "AdminPage", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
{
    <div id="result"></div>

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminUser)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AdminUser, new { @placeholder = "Username", @class = "short" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminUser)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AdminPassword, new { @placeholder = "Password", @type = "password", @class = "short" })
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
}
```

My Controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult AdminPage(MyViewModel model)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           return Content("VALID!", "text/html");
       }
       return Content("NOT VALID!", "text/html");
   }
```

Also in the Web.Config I have:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

and i have the following scripts referenced:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

When the AdminUser field is left empty, the controller returns the "NOT VALID" state to the 'result' div. However I am expecting the validation failure message for AdminUser to show but it doesn't?

One thing to add is that AdminPage is a partial view.

Comment: The controller action AdminPage does not tie up with MachineProvision you use in the form.

Comment: Sorry typo it should have done, that's not the problem here though

Comment: Did you update the jQuery version in your project or are you using the version when you got while creating the project ?

Comment: instead of return ``Content("NOT VALID!", "text/html");`` do :``return View(model);``

Comment: yes - im currently using jquery-2.1.1.min.js, the latest version

Comment: Have you tried updating jQuery and unobtrusive validate via NuGet? i tried your exact code and validation are working properly